# Can't download games on my phone

Tags: games

Every time I try to download a game it tells me to save or cancel with an account that I don't know and didn't put in.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the message you're getting?

Comment: Do you get any error codes  ?? Check whether this error codes match yours https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2781172 and let us know ,.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a different Microsoft account was set up as the primary account on your phone. If you don't know this account then the only way to change our to your Microsoft account is to do a factory reset of your phone.